# Does $|f^\prime|<1$ imply that $\forall_{x,y}|f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y|$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces

I have a task that I think reduces to proving that $f$ is a contraction mapping. We know that $\forall_x|f^\prime(x)|<1$. Therefore if I could prove that $|f^\prime|<1\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y|$ then I think the task would be solved.

I feel this property does hold and that it is also somewhat obvious. Unfortunately, saying that something is *obvious* is *obviously* not a valid proof.

I have feeling proving this belongs to an elementary course on analysis, but it is somehow surprising how much have I forgotten from this course... How to prove this property and does it even hold?

Comment: Maybe using the mean value theorem helps?

Comment: What about $f: \Bbb R \setminus \{ 0 \} \to \Bbb R$, $f(x) = x/|x|$ ?

Comment: Ans what about $x=y$?

Comment: @MartinR Is this supposed to be a counterexample? In each interval on which $f$ is continuous my property holds. Let $x,y>0,x\neq y$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|=0$ but $|x-y|>0$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Is this supposed to be a counterexample? As far as I'm aware $x^\prime=1$ therefore $|f^\prime|\not <1$ therefore my property doesn't have to hold.

Comment: @gaazkam: Exactly. So stating where $f$ is defined should be the first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $|f'(x)|<1 ~\forall x \in (a,b).$

**SIMPLER  PROOF** (thanks to BigbearZzz)

Consider $y<x\in [a, b]$.

By the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), there exists a number $c \in (y,x)$:

$$f'(c) = \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \Rightarrow \\
f(x)-f(y) = (x-y)f'(c) \Rightarrow\\
|f(x)-f(y)| = |x-y||f'(c)|.$$

Since $|f'(c)| <1 $, then:

$$|f(x)-f(y)| = |x-y||f'(c)| < |x-y| \Rightarrow \\
|f(x)-f(y)| < |x-y|.$$

**OLD PROOF**

Consider $y<x\in [a, b]$. Moreover, consider the function $g(x) = x$ (continuous and differentiable everywhere).

By the [Cauchy's mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy's_mean_value_theorem), there exists a number $c \in (y,x)$:

$$\left(f(x)-f(y)\right)g'(c) = \left(g(x)-g(y)\right)f'(c) \Rightarrow\\
\left(f(x)-f(y)\right) = \left(x-y\right)f'(c) \Rightarrow \\
|f(x)-f(y)| = |x-y||f'(c)|.$$

Since $|f'(c)| <1 $, then:

$$|f(x)-f(y)| = |x-y||f'(c)| < |x-y| \Rightarrow \\
|f(x)-f(y)| < |x-y|.$$

Comment: I wonder why you need to use Cauchy MVT when the normal MVT works just fine?

Comment: @BigbearZzz you're right! I think I used it because yesterday I was following a seminar about the mathematical heritage of Cauchy. I'm going to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I am making a guess as to what your final problem is. Draw a careful graph of
$$ \frac{3x + \sqrt{1+x^2 \;}}{4} $$ 
It has no fixpoint.

Comment: Ugh. Is this function a counter-example to my property? If it wasn't, then from Banach fixed-point theorem it would have to have a fixpoint.

Comment: @gaazkam your question has a correct answer already. The warning I am making is for non-compact metric spaces. We may then have $d(f(x), f(y)) < d(x,y)$ while still failing to have fixpoints for $f$  There is yet more that could be said...